# creating a file inside /etc/apt/sources.list.d/

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, chef-infra

I am trying to install `chef` (from opscode) on ubuntu box. I am not much familiar with linux  but I have to install `chef` on linux in quick time.

One of the steps installation guide says

```
Create /etc/apt/sources.list.d/opscode.list
```

What does this line mean? Now should I create a directory `opscode.list` or file?

`/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` directory already exists.

When I try to fire following command ->

```
cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
mkdir opscode.list
```

I get following ->

```
mkdir: cannot create directory `opscode.list': Permission denied
```

How can I resolve the permission denied issue?

Answer (score 10):

use sudo:

```
sudo vi /etc/apt/sources.list.d/opscode.list
```

or maybe via echo:

```
sudo echo "deb http://apt.opscode.com/ <codename> main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/opscode.list
```

When asked for a password, type in YOUR password (not the one from root).

Replace "<codename>" with whatever is needed (according to the tutorial):

> - For Chef 0.9.x, replace codename with the supported distribution
>     codename, such as "lucid".
> - For Chef 0.10.x, replace codename with the
>     codename, suffixed with "-0.10", for example, "lucid-0.10".

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
echo "deb http://apt.opscode.com/ <codename> main" | sudo tee 
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/opscode.list
```